# Setting focus of an input element in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to set the focus of an input element in Vue.js. I found some help online but none of the explanation worked for me.

Here's my code :

```
<template>
    <form method="post" action="" v-on:submit.prevent="search">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Person name" required v-model="name" v-el="nameInput" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Company" required v-model="company" v-el="domainInput" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn show-m" />
    </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            contacts: [],
            name: null,
            company: null
        }
    },
    ready: {
        // I tried the following :
        this.$$.nameInput.focus();
        this.$els.nameInput.focus();
        // None of them worked !
    }
    methods: {
        search: function (event) {
            // ...

            // I also would like to give the focus here, once the form has been submitted.
            // And here also, this.$$ and this.$els doesn't work
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

I tried `this.$$.nameInput.focus();` and `this.$els.nameInput.focus();` for what I could find online to target the focus, but `this.$$` is undefined, and `this.$els` is empty.

If that can help, I'm using vue.js v1.0.15

Thank you for your help.

Comment: **Note**: [in Vue2, `v-el` *directive* was migrated to the `ref` *attribute*](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#v-el-and-v-ref-replaced)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In vue 2.x you can solve it with a [directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html).

```
Vue.directive('focus', {
    inserted: function (el) {
        el.focus()
    }
})
```

Then you can use `v-focus` attribute on inputs and other elements:

```
<input v-focus>
```

Comment: It did work. But I had to use

```inserted: function (el) {
    el.__vue__.focus()
  }
```

Maybe it's because I use vue element-ui.

Comment: And how I can do it via method??

Answer (score 17):

## Another solution using Vue 2.x and `ref`.

You can use the [`ref/$refs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs) attribute to target your input and focus it.

In the example a simple method is used which can target the inputs using the ref attribute supplied to the inputs.
Then access the `$refs` property on your instance to get a reference to the DOM element.

```js
<script>
export default {
    // ...
  mounted: function () {
    this.focusInput('nameInput');
  },
  methods: {
    // This is the method that focuses the element
    focusInput: function ( inputRef ) {
      // $refs is an object that holds the DOM references to your inputs
      this.$refs[inputRef].focus();
    },

    search: function (event) {
      this.focusInput('domainInput');
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <form method="post" action="" v-on:submit.prevent="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Person name" required v-model="name" ref="nameInput" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Company" required v-model="company" ref="domainInput" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn show-m" />
  </form>
</template>
```

This solution is best for a one off situation or for a reusable component. For a more global approach the directive is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

## Setting focus inside a child element

*(for those of you that struggled for hours like me)*

**Parent:**

```
<template>
  <div @click="$refs.theComponent.$refs.theInput.focus()">
    <custom-input ref="theComponent"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Child (`CustomInput.vue`):**

```
<template>
  <input ref="theInput"/>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues.

**First** of all, *v-el*s are defined like this:

```
<input v-el:input-element/>
```

That'll turn the variable to a camelCase in the code. You can read up more on this weird functionality [here](http://vuejs.org/api/#v-el).

Other than that, you should be able to access the variable through `this.$els.inputElement`. Mind you, it will only appear in the component that you're defining that element (or the main app itself, if you defined it there).

**Secondly**, the automatic focusing does not seem to be working on Firefox (43.0.4), at least on my machine. Everything works great on Chrome, and focuses as expected.

Comment: That's odd, why this way of functionning ? (if you have any idea). The `v-el="XXX"` is more logical no ?

Comment: But this works, so you shall have my accepted answer :) Thank you

Comment: [This](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1292) is the basic thought process on the current functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ref` I managed to focus an Input on `mounted` like this.

**Template :**

```
 <b-form-input  v-model="query" ref="searchInput" ></b-form-input>
```

**Javascript :**

```
  mounted(){
    this.$refs.searchInput.$el.focus()
  }
```

Comment: Even though correct, the default linter with Vue-cli and Vue will recommend you to use `this.$refs.searchInput.$el.focus()` ;)

Comment: @CyrilN. using `$` in object field cannot be used in most of the other languages. So I get confused now and then. Fixed it in the edit.

Answer (score 2):

## Vue 3.x

Use a custom directive.

```
app.directive('focus', {
    mounted(el) { 
      el.focus() 
    }
})
```

Here is how you use it:

**Step 1:**

```
// main.js

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router)

 app.directive('focus', {
     mounted(el) { // When the bound element is inserted into the DOM...
       el.focus() // Focus the element
     }
 })

/* Optional: 
   Add a slight delay if the input does not focus.

app.directive('focus', {
    mounted(el) { // When the bound element is inserted into the DOM...
        setTimeout(() => {
            el.focus() // Focus the element
        }, 500)
    }
}) */

await router.isReady()
app.mount('#app')
```

Then in your component:

**Step 2:**

```
// MyInput.vue

<input v-focus>
```

Vue [docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/custom-directives.html#_3-x-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

There is something that needs to be added to these answers here. First of all in my case when I use `ref` it returns an array. For example I want user to enter a 5 digit number and I have 5 inputs for each digit:

```
<div v-for="n, i in 5" :key="i">
    <input
        inputmode="numeric"
        type="text"
        v-model="codeDigits[n]"
        autocomplete="off"
        @input="typeOnCodeInput(n)"
        :ref="`code-input-${n}`"
    />
</div>
```

And in my `methods` section I have defined a method named `"typeOnCodeInput"` and in this method I want to select next input and focus on it. So this is how my method is written:

```
typeOnCodeInput (n) {
this.$refs[`code-input-${n+1}`][0].focus()
}
```

**My Point Is :** In some setups `this.$refs['code-input-1']` or `this.$refs['code-input-2']` or... They all return an array.
So that's why I have that `[0]` before `.focus()`

FYI: *When I was searching for answers, this array thing was not mentioned in so many answers and it was a key concept to solve the problem in my case. So, I added this answer and it may help some people who have the same issue just like mine*

Answer (score -1):

According to vue 2.x, you can also register "directive" locally in component to get autofocus.

just write directive in component:

```
export default {
  directives: { focus: {
    inserted: function (el) {
    el.focus()
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Then in a template, you can use the new v-focus attribute on any element, like this:

```
<input type="text" v-focus>
```